# python selenium send_key() is not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, automation

i am new at automation. i am trying to enter a sting in the text box of Omegle and press enter but it is showing me an error :

*selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element  is not reachable by keyboard*

[here](https://www.omegle.com/) is the webpage link where i wanna access the text box.

```
import time
import random
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get("https://www.omegle.com/")
time.sleep(random.randint(2, 5))
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
time.sleep(random.randint(1, 5))
button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[@class='topicplaceholder']")
button.click()
button.send_keys("panda")
button.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Comment: If it is a button that you clicked it stands to reason that you should not be able to send a key to it because it is not a text input point. Re-evaluate the website for a better way to interact with it

Comment: how can i find the input point, in  the project i am stuck again with the same problem but at different text field, can you please tell me how i can find an interactable point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I've tried this, it's working.**

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys
import Keys
import time

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get("https://www.omegle.com/")
text_area = browser.find_element_by_class_name("topicplaceholder")
text_area.click()
input = browser.find_element_by_class_name("newtopicinput")
input.send_keys("panda")
input.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

**I hope having solved your matter.**

Answer (score 1):

Should work:

```
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/div/div/div[1]/span[2]')
button.click()
button.send_keys('panda')
button.send_keys(u'\ue007')
```

Comment: it's throwing an error selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <span class="topicplaceholder"> is not reachable by keyboard
,thank you for helping me